# Get length of the teaser

Tags: nodes

I need to get the setting on what length the teaser of a custom made content type is set.

I tried Google'ing for it, but so far I have ziltch results.
I also tried looking in the database, in the field_config_instance, field_config and the variable tables, but they couldn't give me a value either...

Now, I'm hoping you experts could help me to point me to the right direction?
Would be appreciated. :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you want to get the length of teaser ? For any specific purpose ?

Comment: well, I want to display a piece of the node content from a custom module if the content is longer than the desired amount of characters, but I want to show the full node (without the read-more link) if it's less than the amount of chars defined in the display-settings on admin/structure/types/manage/[content type]/display/teaser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check [ReadMoreControl](http://drupal.org/project/readmorecontrol) module, this might help you..By this module you can add Read more links to other supported view modes